# How to find the rational root in this case. Is there a relationship between all the roots?

Tags: polynomials

[image]

I know that the complex roots come in pairs and I know the Vieta's formulas.
But I still don't know how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $2+i$ is a root of $g(z),g'(z),g''(z),$ it is a triple root of $g(z).$ As you pointed out, due to real coefficients is also $2-i$ a root of each of $g(z),g'(z),g''(z),$ therefore it is a triple root. Compute

$$(z-(2+i))(z-(2-i))=z^2-4z+5.$$

Thus $$g(z)=(z^2-4z+5)^3(z-r),$$ where $r$ is the real root. The free coefficient is a product of the free coefficients from the above factored form. Hence you have $5^3(-r)=-53$ and $$r=\frac{53}{125}$$ is the real root.

Comment: Why I got downvote?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*

(a) $2\pm i$ is a triple root of $g$ and so $g(z)=(z-2+i)^3(z-2-i)^3h(z)$, with $h$ of degree $1$.

(b) $-a_6$ is the sum of the roots, counted with multiplicity.

Comment: What does that mean? I know that 2±i are both complex roots of the polynomial.

Comment: [Multiple root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)#Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial)

Comment: And then how can I find the real root? DO I have to find a exactly h(z)?

Comment: @user31353, evaluate at $z=0$ to find $b$ in $h(z)=z-b$.

Comment: when z=0 g(z) is not 0 so 0 is not a root

Comment: b=-a0 =58x So is 58 a real root? why?

Comment: @user31353: From the problem alone, can you compute $g(0)$? Then using the hint, can you compute $h(0)$? You might find it useful to compute $(x-2-i)(x-2+i)$.